# Android emulator only shows logo on OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

Im starting to learn Android programming however my emulator doesn't work.  It only shows the android logo and Ive been running it for about 45 minutes.  Ive tried creating a new AVD with different settings.  Using the GPU only shows the logo, and using the snapshot feature shows only a black screen.  Also Ive tried a variety of different sizes for the RAM.  Im using the Nexus 5 setting with Lollipop/ Google APIs x86.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also Im getting these messages on the console:
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Thanks...

Comment: use genymotion as it's fastest emulator